# question on getting the following information for Ubuntu running on Vmware player

Tags: networking, vmware, vmware-player

I am trying to follow the answer posted in [Configuring Ubuntu vmware guest NAT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302011/configuring-ubuntu-vmware-guest-nat)  to solve the similar issue.

At first, I would like to know how to get the following information as the Kingsly wrote in his answer

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't take screen shots but "edit" the question and copy-paste the text into your question if referring to another question.  You've got enough reputation to do this...

Secondly, that looks like an `ipconfig` from Windows...

The equivalent command in Ubuntu would be the `ifconfig` command combined with a `route` command.

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) Just click the little grey check-mark under the "0" now.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0 and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask